# How to preserve whitespace in H2 database?

Tags: database, h2, in-memory-database

### SQL

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE
   (    
    "MY_COLUMN" CHAR(4 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(MY_COLUMN)
   );

Merge into MY_TABLE KEY (MY_COLUMN) VALUES('ABC ');

select *,LENGTH(MY_COLUMN) AS len from MY_TABLE;
```

### output

[image]

I am expecting **"ABC "** with space. i.e length is **4**

I had tried these urls

1 and 2 return "ABC". But in 3, i got "Unsupported connection setting "PRESERVEWHITESPACE"

```
1) jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
    
2) jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb;**MODE=Oracle**;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
    
3) jdbc:h2:file:./target/db/testdb;preserveWhitespace=true;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
```

Tried with h2 version **1.4.200**.

**Any solution for this?**

Comment: If you switch to `VARCHAR(4)` all works out of the box. I just tried it as `"MY_COLUMN" VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,`.

Comment: Don't use CHAR as a datatype, even for columns which you expect to always be a fixed length.